# Write a binary tree in hadoop FS

Tags: java, hadoop, binary-tree, writable

I need to write a binary tree to HDFS, which i will use to represent a desicion tree. But in order to do that i first need to create a BinaryTreeNode class, which will be the tree node. These are my class attributes:

```
private String name;
private String attribute;
private String attType;
private String condition;
private String lines;
private BinaryTreeNode leftChild;
private BinaryTreeNode rightChild;
```

So now i need to implement the write and readFields methods for reading and writing these nodes. These are what i have done:

```
public void write(DataOutput d) throws IOException 
{
    d.writeUTF(name);
    d.writeUTF(attribute);
    d.writeUTF(attType);
    d.writeUTF(condition);
    d.writeUTF(lines);
    //SOMETHIN FOR LEFT AND RIGHT CHILD
}

public void readFields(DataInput di) throws IOException 
{
    name=di.readUTF();
    attribute=di.readUTF();
    attType=di.readUTF();
    condition=di.readUTF();
    lines=di.readUTF();
    //SOMETHIN FOR LEFT AND RIGHT CHILD
}

BinaryTreeNode read(DataInput in) throws IOException
{
     BinaryTreeNode ob = new BinaryTreeNode();
     ob.readFields(in);
     return ob;
}
```

What i cant think of is how to write and read my 2 child nodes. Note that the tree is going to be build recursively and every node will have 0-2 childs. So my later purpose is to have a BinaryTree class that will have the attribute BinaryTreeNode root. Thanks

Comment: So it is a binary search tree. You can't construct a binary search tree from one traverse. You need to write both `in-order, post-order` or `in-order, pre-order` traverse, so you can construct the main tree.

Comment: All i need is a way to save and load my tree. If i somehow find a way to save and load my root as an object, my goal will be fullfiled. Well it is not a binary search tree. It is a desicion tree used in machine learning. Since i am making binary splits, it is  a binary tree. I need to save and load that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution. I dont know if it is efficient enough but it works. Here is what i did. These are in  my class definition:

```
    public void write(DataOutput d) throws IOException
    {
      d.writeUTF(name);
      d.writeUTF(attribute);
      d.writeUTF(attType);
      d.writeUTF(condition);
      d.writeUTF(lines);
      ObjectWritable left=new ObjectWritable(BinaryTreeNode.class,leftChild);
      left.write(d);
      ObjectWritable right=new ObjectWritable(BinaryTreeNode.class,rightChild);
      right.write(d);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput di) throws IOException
    {
      name=di.readUTF();
      attribute=di.readUTF();
      attType=di.readUTF();
      condition=di.readUTF();
      lines=di.readUTF();
      leftChild=(BinaryTreeNode) ObjectWritable.readObject(di, new Configuration());
      rightChild=(BinaryTreeNode) ObjectWritable.readObject(di, new Configuration());

    }
```

And this is how i use them:

For writing:

```
      BinaryTreeNode bla=new BinaryTreeNode();
      //set the attributes
      ObjectWritable obj=new ObjectWritable(BinaryTreeNode.class,bla);
      obj.write(dos);
```

For reading:

```
      BinaryTreeNode bla=new BinaryTreeNode();
      bla= (BinaryTreeNode) ObjectWritable.readObject(in, conf);
```

This works fine. Now i am able to create my decision tree and store it just by storing my root. :D

Comment: Your readFields & Write function implementation is not looking proper. Instead of name=di.readUTF(); you have to use name.readUTF(di)

Answer (score 2):

> I need to write a binary tree to HDFS
>
> All i need is a way to save and load my tree.

What's the reason to go with HDFS? HDFS is a distributed file system on which any type of data/files can be stored. You have write a lot of code to store and retrieve the graphs effectively on large scale.

You can store and retrieve graphs from graph oriented databases like [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orient-db.htm) and [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/).

Also, there are open source frameworks like [Apache Giraph](http://incubator.apache.org/giraph/), [Apache Hama](http://incubator.apache.org/hama/) and [GoldenOrb](http://goldenorbos.org/). There might also be bindings to interact from Java programs.

Comment: I am trying to implement this http://www.bayardo.org/ps/vldb2009.pdf .  I need to sent to each mapper the current constructed desicion tree, known as the MFile. I will take a look of those you sent me . Thanks. Although i think it is much simpler. I managed yesterday to save the root of my tree, which had 2 childs. I am still working with it. I want something easy, and not something fast and effective. Thanks :D